# Why do the boost interprocess named mutex docs say each process should have it's own named mutex?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

I'm trying to use boost interprocess named mutex, and I'm a little confused about this line from the documentation : 
*A mutex with a global name, so it can be found from different processes. This mutex can't be placed in shared memory, and each process should have it's own named_mutex.*

I want different processes to use the same mutex, not each to have their own. What does that line mean exactly?

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/named_mutex.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems to be badly worded. It should read something like:

> ... and each process should have it's own `named_mutex` ***class instance.***

Also have a look at `named_mutex` example usage [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.mutexes). You will need to scroll down to "named mutex example".